# How to inherit CSS of parent site and apply it on HTML rendered using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I would like to develop a Javascript code which would get data from a Web Service and render html for displaying details.

Users need to just place this Javascript on any page on their Website to use this feature.

**The problem I will face is that the html generated by my Javascript will have a different CSS to that of the Website which is using my Javascript. Is there any way that the html generated by my Javascript would inherit the CSS of the Website where my Javascript is being used.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a script to run on any websites, you should expect the developer of that website to work on the styling of your generated HTML. Just simply display the HTML there, maybe with basic class names and styles.

A lot of cookie legals displaying that way on multiple websites.
Example: https://policy.app.cookieinformation.com/6f7f86/cubiscan.dk/declaration-da.js
That script is to put on any websites, to display few tables of cookie usage information.

If you want to overwrite their CSS, use iframe or inline styles, inline CSS.